# How to call WebServices in Puppet manifests?

Tags: puppet

We need to invoke an external webservice via Puppet. The steps provided to me consist of invoking webservices using curl command. Is there anyway to invoke webservices natively via Puppet instead of calling curl commands instead ?

The curl example is provided below

```
curl -k -v –H "Content-Type:application/json" –-data some_data_file https://service.server.com/some_service
```

Comment: Is what you really asking is how to interact with a REST API with an intrinsic Puppet resource instead of an `exec`?

Comment: Do you want to invoke the webservice during catalog *building* (when the manifest is indeed relevant), or during catalog *application* on the target machine (when the manifest may not even be available).

Comment: I want to avoid using "curl" from within the Puppet manifest. I am currently using curl and when I receive data back from the webservice call, I need to use Unix tools to parse and extract the necessary information. I want to avoid that in favour of something more elegant. Does that help answer your question ?

Comment: No, that didn't answer either of our questions. If you answer John's question, it will probably also answer mine.